# Javascript - Creating file from huge variable

Tags: javascript, file

I'm trying to save a 2gb variable into a file.This variable comes from webtorrent. I tried to use the blob url , but it crashes as it is bigger than max blob size. I also tried StreamSaver.js and got 2 different problems. By writting periodically while I download the variable, streamSaver fails at some point (no idea why, it writes like 500 mb then crashes). By writting it all at the end it obviously crashes the tab. I even tried to write it at the end but chunks by chunks but nothing seems to get this working. So I was wondering if you guys knew how I could save this variable to a file (any API, tricks, I'll take anything)

Comment: Why is this JavaScript related?

Comment: As this variable is "created" by webtorrent on client side and I'm trying to save it as a file on client side

Comment: Save it using Curl.

Comment: What do you mean by using curl ? Do you have any examples or documentations on how to use curl in a browser ?